# I am a Filipino in Qatar who wants to visit Dubai and look for a job there

Tags: visas, transit, filipino-citizens, uae, qatar

What are the things I need to secure in order for me to get through to Dubai? I am planning to go there with a flight connecting via Oman? Is it possible or do I need to also get a visa to Oman and exit there before I go to Dubai?

I am planning to get a 90-day visit visa there in Dubai and look for a job. Is it possible for me to enter the country via a two-leg flight Qatar-Oman-Dubai?

Comment: I removed the last paragraph, its off-topic. Otherwise I am afraid your question will be closed

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated due to the recent diplomatic problems between Qatar and some GCC countries. You cannot fly directly from Doha to the UAE (Saudi and Bahrain as well, so driving isn't an option as well).

Your GCC resident Qatari visa will not entitle you to enter the UAE anymore, so you must apply for a visa, which you already figured out.

As for flying via a third country, it's allowed. You can fly either via Kuwait or Oman.

Most of these inquiries were answered in this [Gulf News article](http://gulfnews.com/news/uae/general/ways-you-might-be-affected-by-qatar-situation-1.2039817) (it's considered an official newspaper).

As for hunting for a job while on visit visa, it's ok, as long as you will not start working or getting paid.